# Printing array elements in one second intervals using sleep()

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, sleep

I have an array that contains chars. 
I am trying to print out an element once every second.

```
int i=0;
while (i< 110)
{
    cout << arrayValue[i]<<"\0";
    sleep(1);
    i++;
 }
```

This for some reason just waits for 110 seconds and than prints out the whole array at once.

But if i add a new line after every element it works just fine

```
 int i=0;
while (i< 110)
{
    cout << arrayValue[i]<<"\0";
    cout<< endl;
    sleep(1);
    i++;
 }
```

Any recommendation on how to get each element to print chronologically without having to make a newline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This for some reason just waits for 110 seconds and than prints out the whole array at once.

Actually it doesn't, but your output is *buffered*. There is buffering in the C++ stream object, in the OS data pipe, and in your terminal.

Your stream thinks it would be a waste of resources passing characters through one at a time, and it's kind of right: the stream doesn't know you have a second to wait in between each one.

You don't need the newline, though; you can basically force a flush like so:

```
std::cout << std::flush;
```

Recall that `std::cout << std::endl` is equivalent to `std::cout << '\n' << std::flush`, and it's the `'\n'` part that you don't want.

This is usually enough but you *may* also need to reconfigure your terminal to turn off line buffering. (That's unlikely for *output* but quite common for input).

Comment: Thanks for your help!
That fixed it.